# Indentation with Angular 17 new control flow in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-language-service

I'm using VS Code and having issues with the Angular 17 indentation (Alt+Shift+F). I'd like to change how the indentation is working with Angular 17 views.  Currently with the new control flow it's doing this:
[image]

I'd like to see it do this:
[image]

I'm not sure if the issue is with the Angular Language Service, Prettier, or VS Code.

Can anyone please guide me as this is driving me a bit crazy.

Comment: did you find a solution on this?

Comment: @OriolLopez, it's sorted out now with the new version of Prettier.  It's not everything I'm looking for, but close.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prettier 3.1 supports intending Angular's new control flow.

Run `npm i prettier@3.1 --save-dev` to install v3.1 in your `package.json` as a dev dependency. Then, be sure that you have the Prettier VSCode extension installed, which uses the version from your `node_modules`. Finally, press `Cmd+Shift+P`, search for `Format...`, and format with Prettier.

Comment: IT supports it but doesn't indent

Answer (score 14):

None of the other answers worked for me individually, but combining dylhunn and Sadra Rahmani's answers did the trick:

1. **Install Prettier as a Dev Dependency**

   First, add Prettier to your project. This is important because the globally installed Prettier didn't work for me. Use this command:

   ```
   npm i -D prettier
   ```
2. **Add a `.prettierrc` File**

   Then, create a `.prettierrc` file in your project's root. Put the following inside:

   ```
   {
     "overrides": [
       {
         "files": "*.html",
         "options": {
           "parser": "angular"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   Note: Simply putting `{"parser": "angular"}` there broke formatting for .ts files for me.
3. **Restart**

   Restart Visual Studio Code to start using the new configuration.

Comment: Yeah! This works. Make sure you restart the vscode after applying these changes.

Comment: In my case the formatting effectively changed but it fromats in a weird way tags from ionic framework (as <ion-button>). Instead of keeping it on the same line it breaks a line before the closing tag ">" of each ionic tags. Any clue how to solve that?

Answer (score 5):

For any future visitors tackling with indentation of Prettier.
I mean something like this:

```
@if (pageData$ | async; as model) { @if (!model.loading) { @if (model.value) { @for (item of model.value; track item.id)){
...
}  }  }  }
```

Note that all of IFs and FOR are in one line!!

I could finally fix this with the help of [this comment](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/15833#issuecomment-1862664659)!

Please install the latest version of prettier and then generate a .prettierrc file in the root directory.

Then add this json to it

```
{
    "parser": "angular"
}
```

After adding this json the prettier must work like a charm!

Result:

```
@if (pageData$ | async; as model) {
    @if (!model.loading) {
      @if (model.value) {
        @for (item of model.value; track item.id) {
           ...
        }    
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 3):

The angular service doesn't do any formatting, it's responsible for syntax highlighting and parsing the template to match the tokens with the component file.

This is a prettier issue.

You should track [this issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/14991) on the Prettier repo.

Comment: But what is the solution for those who don't use Prettier? I don't really like to have my attributes aligned like Prettier is forcing me to. I'd like to have the default formatter of Visual Studio Code but with indentation for the code flow.

Comment: I agree with this.  I'm not a fan of all the things Prettier does, but I'm willing to go along with it if it means my entire project follows a standard that I don't have to put a ton of time into maintaining. 

These are the settings I used to get it closest to my liking:

"prettier": {
 "tabWidth": 4,
 "useTabs": true,
 "singleAttributePerLine": false,
 "bracketSameLine":true,
 "printWidth": 400,
 "proseWrap": "never",
 "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css"
}

Comment: You should open a specific issue on the framework repo. (ie formatting without prettier). Not sure what approache the team would take though

Comment: Prettier 3.1 is now available. AFAIK, it is the only formatter that supports Angular's new template syntax features. In the past, you could use any old HTML formatter, but now that Angular templates have evolved into non-HTML syntax, you need custom support, above and beyond the default HTML formatting in VSCode.

Comment: @dylhunn but it doesn't seem like Prettier 3.1 indents the code inside the brackets.

Comment: @Spock For me prettier does indent the code correctly. If you have issues with it, you should open an issue in their issue tracker.

Comment: @JSONDerulo thanks . Awesome name you have btw :)